# I need to create a chart in my enyo project. Which properties are used to do this?

Tags: enyo

I'm new on enyo, so I don't have yet a full knowledge in this framework.

I've been looking for a property of enyo that I be able to make a chart of bars. But the only things I found in the web, was about using the "enyo.Control", what i think that don't have nothing to do about this. 
Can anyone help with some tips?

Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enyo has certain widgets available in the Onyx library, but I don't think there are any charting/graph ones. I guess you could use a ProgressBar kind to sort of be a bar graph.

Some developers have used Flot successfully: http://www.flotcharts.org/

Answer (score 0):

Enyo-ified YUI charts are in the pipeline: https://enyojs.atlassian.net/browse/ENYO/component/10802. So watch this issue for updates.